# What is the name of this category of visual artwork? Is this pop art?

Tags: vector, illustration, terminology, style-identification

There is a style of artwork that I want to learn to create. It abstracts away most detail, but it is not really abstract art. It has a lot in common visually with vector illustrations, but some of the examples I see are created using markers, acrylics, and other physical approaches (as opposed to digital). Here are examples (all motorsports, but I also see this style with some vintage travel posters):

[example 1](http://www.timlayzell.com/motor_World-Domination.htm)

[example 2](http://mihafurlan.com/index.php/2015/08/12/fight-to-the-finish/)

[example 3](http://inkpad.art/news/designed-with-inkpad/martin-coffey/)

Comment: I don't think these are the same style. Nos. 1 and 2 are similar, you could call them pop art, but No. 3 looks like a 3D render of a car, and to me it stands out as totally different to the other two.

Answer (score 2):

"Pop art" seems to fit the bill to me.

It really *doesn't* matter if an illustration is created in a traditional manner or digital manner. That doesn't necessary alter the name of a style, if there even is a name (not everything has a name).